# How this apex statement work?

Tags: apex

```
String x = 'The !shorn! sheep !sprang!.';
System.debug (x.replaceAll ('!(.*?)!', '$1'));
```

How does the regex in second statement work?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really any Apex question. Have a read about regex.
Also you can use an online tester e.g. http://regexpal.com/
Enter your match expression !(.*?)! in the top box.
Put your test string in the botton: The !shorn! sheep !sprang!.
See that !shorn! and !sheep! are the matches.
Understand what replace is doing.

Comment: So poetic, so philosophical ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_verse ?